# LSF: Dependent Job with failed dependency

Tags: lsf

I have 2 jobs Job1 and Job2,

Job2 depend on "done(Job1->id)",

If Job 1 errored out and has a status of exit instead of done, how do I get job2 to exit too?

Currently I see that J2 is stuck in pend state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [orphaned job termination feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/bsub.ti.1.html).  Submit your second job with

```
bsub -w 'done(Job1->id)' -ti ...
```

Then if Job1 fails, Job2 will be killed right away.